# Setting options with Linq

Tags: c#, .net, sql, linq-to-entities

I'm in a situation where I want to add the equivalent of the sql statement

```
SET QUERY_GOVERNOR_COST_LIMIT
```

to my query I created with linq to entities.

How would I go about that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var conn = ((EntityConnection)Context.Connection).StoreConnection;
```

Also, in EF 4 you can do `Context.ExecuteStoreQuery`

Comment: Though rather verbose, this was indeed what we used.
Sadly it appeared not to be core issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a connection yourself, execute the statement, wrap the connection in a `EntityConnection` and that as parameter to the `ObjectContext` constructor. This way the `ObjectContext` is executed within the context of that connection.

Comment: We wanted to do such a thing, but we get our context from a factory. The factory is out of scope. Is there another way to execute the sqlCommand on the (existing) context's conncetion somehow?